# Application.Ontime Procedure Code Not Working in Thisworkbook Module

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I would like to keep this entire code in **ThisWorkbook Module only**.  But its not working when I keep the EventCode/ProcedureCode in Thisworkbook Module.

```
Dim alertTime As Date
Sub StartMacro()
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventCode"
End Sub
Sub StopMacro()
    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "EventCode", , False
End Sub
Sub EventCode()
    MsgBox "Okay", vbInformation, "I am working"
    ThisWorkbook.StartMacro
End Sub
```

The same is working fine If I keep the Event Code in New Module.

Any suggestions about how to make it work by keeping the entire code in ThisWorkbook module.

Comment: You need to use `"ThisWorkbook.EventCode"` as the routine name. Why do you want it in that module - it doesn't really belong there.

Comment: Ah!!! I spent nearly half day in finding the solution for this issue by converting codes to new module and all.   Thanks for the quick solution :)

Answer (score -1):

Hello please use the code below... this should be working.
You start with calling StartTheMachine and you stop it with calling StopMacro.

```
Dim bTickerIsOn As Boolean
Sub StartMacro()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "EventCode", , bTickerIsOn
End Sub
Sub StopMacro()
    bTickerIsOn = False
End Sub
Sub StartTheMachine()
    bTickerIsOn = True
    StartMacro
End Sub
Sub EventCode()
    Range("A1") = Time 'I used this instead of the msgbox to show the action
    If bTickerIsOn Then StartMacro
End Sub
```

Good luck!